# jsoup how to select from div attribute

Tags: java, jsoup

How to select the url from this code

```
<div class="main_news_lp_img3" 
     onclick="location.href='?news_view=77f1f3883c4ceac3'" 
     style="background-image: url('uploads/resize2/61b96f91b599c754461eca5891a87951.JPG');">
</div>
```

I want to select `url()` content - this part

```
uploads/resize2/61b96f91b599c754461eca5891a87951.JPG
```

Comment: Hello! What have you done so far?

Comment: Have you already written any code? Have you tried anything? Show us, we will tell you where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *Jsoup* you will not be able to select specific "elements" of a `style` attribute. You have to read the whole attribute and then parse the contents yourself:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("your-url").get()
// select all "div" elements with a class name "main_news_lp_img3"
for (Element el : doc.select("div.main_news_lp_img3")) {
    // get the "style" attribute value
    String style = el.attr("style");
    // parse the url from the attribute
    String url = StringUtils.substringBetween(style, "background-image: url('", "')");
    // do something with url...
}
```

Here I use `StringUtils.substringBetween` from *Apache commons-lang*, but you could also use a regular-expression or implement your own `substringBetween` method.

Answer (score 0):

It is something like this (pseudo) :

Edit :

```
htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect(HtmlUrl).get();
Elements articles = htmlDocument.select(DIV);
String url = null;
for (Element article : articles) {
Element element = article.select(DIV).first();
if (element.attr(style) != null) {
     url = element.attr(style);
  }
}
```

Comment: but not this what i want i just wan get the url in this code

Comment: `element#attr` does not return null values (it returns empty string if there's no match)

Comment: oh i didn't noticed that :)